# When does it makes sense to have multiple datatypes for one attribute?

Tags: database, mongodb, types, nosql, schema

In MongoDB or other NoSQL Databases you dont have a schema. For example you can save the "name" of an employee as an String but also as an integer. You cant do this in SQL Databases. But it doesnt really make sense to save a name = 3 or something like that. My question is when does it make sense to have different datatypes for one attribute? Can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the flexibility. NoSql covers lots of use-cases such as analytics, IOTs, payments, fraud detection, etc. If you look carefully, all are either semi structured or unstructured data. Flexible schema makes things easier in terms of incremental development. But when you use different data types for a field, you will end up with multiple conditional logics.

For example, you need to analyse all the university, school students' details for the vaccination related analytics. If you see id of one school may be numeric, other may be alpha-numeric, other may have characters like -.

If you need to follow strict schema, you need to preprocess it before loading. OrElse you can live with the data with few conditional conversions.

If you see another example date fields, you either can have timestamps, Date objects, Strings. When you query on this date field, you need to apply conversions.

NoSQL is not only about types, about entire schema. You don't need to forcefully set default values for missing fields. You can have complex nested data types. You can quickly get started with your business need when using NoSql as you don't need to worry much about tables, relationships. But in the long-run, your nosql schema will evolve and get a matured state. If you just want to do ad hoc analysis, you can get started with your unstructured/semi=structured data.